# AngularJS ChartJS - Multiline with diff no. of data points for each line

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using [angular-chart.js](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) which is extension on [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) in my page to create multiline chart.

In my multiline chart, each line may have different set of data points. For example, the chart has 2 lines A & B. Then x-axis labels would be of fixed # like months - Jan to March. The line A can have data points for month Jan & Feb and line B can have data points for Jan & March.  I'm not able to make it work using angularjs but according to [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1544), it is possible using chartjs.

Example Code:
[Plnkr Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/aM9mMP5liENQMa8nfOE9?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="DashboardApp">
<div ng-controller="MultiLineChartCtrl">
  <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick" height="250px"></canvas>
</div>
```

```
var dbapp = angular.module('DashboardApp', ['chart.js']);

dbapp.controller('MultiLineChartCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope) {

$scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April"];
$scope.series = ['Person A', 'Person B'];
$scope.data = [];
$scope.data.push({
  labels: ["January", "February", "March"],
  data: [4.43, 6.27, 6.74]
});
$scope.data.push({
  labels: ["January", "March", "April"],
  data: [6.43, 5.27, 7.74]
});


$scope.options = {
  limitLines: [{
    label: 'Target',
    value: 1,
    color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .9)'
  }],
  steppedLine: true,
  showLines: true,
  elements: {
    line: {
      fill: false,
    }
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
        show: true,
        labelString: 'Month'
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
        show: true,
        labelString: 'Value'
      },
      ticks: {
        suggestedMin: 0,
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'top',
    fill: false
  }
};
$scope.$on('create', function(event, chart) {
  var legend = chart.generateLegend();
  console.log(legend);
});

 }
]);
```